# Can't a function return a string without pointers?

Tags: c

I am having a strange problem while returning a string.
it says can not convert int to const char*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>
/*The above program shows that you can not return a string from a function normally*/
char check(char str[]);
void main(void)
{
    char str[30],str2[30];
    printf("Enter a sentence:");
    gets(str);
    strcpy(str2,check(str));
    getch();
}
char  check(char str[30])
{
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to return a char* instead

Comment: Only the char* works, you have also to change the prototype of the function

Answer (score 4):

No, strings are not intrinsic data types in C. See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Also, forget that `gets()` exists and use `fgets()` if you don't want to build bugs into your code. http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html

Answer (score 3):

The C programming language does not have the data type "string". C supports char arrays and pointers to char.

You can address an array of char by using a pointer though:

```
char *p;
char str[30];

p = str;
```

Your function must return a pointer to character. Changing your code to

```
char* check(char str[30])
{
    return str;
}
```

would work. You must keep in mind that you return the address of the argument that has been passed to function.

If you want to fill any result variable in the function, pass the address to the function:

```
int check(char* result, char str[]);

void main(void)
{
    char str[30], str2[30];

    printf("Enter a sentence:");
    gets(str);

    if (check(str2, str))
    {
      printf("check succeeded %s\n", str2);
    }

    getch();
}

int check(char* result, char str[30])
{
    int success;

    success = ....;

    if (success)
    {
        strcpy(result, str);
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Is it something like i was returning the address of the string and as the stack states,the function is going to kill after it has ended,so there was no address left afterwards,so its lame to return a address from a function

Comment: returning an address from a function is fine, provided that the pointed memory "life" will endure; local variables' memory is "trashed" at the end of the function, so it can contain everything: the pointer can be valid, but the pointed data are lost.

Answer (score 2):

Are you missing "*" in the return type of check function?

it should be

```
char*
```

instead of

```
char
```

Comment: name of the array is in fact a pointer, you can dereference first element writing *array_name, the second *(array_name+1) and so on.

Comment: Ahh!Got it"Name of the array is the address of the array!"
the famous quote .

Comment: In that context yes, but not in all.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>
/*The above program shows that you can not return a string from a function normally*/
char check(char str[]);
void main(void)
{
   char str[30],str2[30];
   printf("Enter a sentence:");
   gets(str);
   strcpy(str2,check(str));
   getch();
}
char  *check(char str[30])
{
    return str;
}
```

You could also modify the string within the function without returning it providing you don't try to reallocate its size, for example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>
/*The above program shows that you can not return a string from a function normally*/
void check(char *str);
void main(void)
{
   char str2[30];
   char *str;

   str = malloc(30);
   printf("Enter a sentence:");
   gets(str);
   check(str);
   strcpy(str2,str);
   getch();
}
void check(char *str)
{
    strcpy(str, "test");
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to change the prototype too.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
/*The above program shows that you can not return a string from a function normally*/
char *check(char **str);

int main(void)
{
    char str[30],str2[30];
    char *p;
    p=str;
    printf("Enter a sentence:");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    strcpy(str2,check(&p));
    printf("You said: %s\n", str2);

    return 0;
}

char  *check(char **str)
{
    return *str;
}
```